# Angular HttpInterceptor - Any Service Injected returns Undefined TypeError

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

**Problem:**

I'm unable to inject ANY service into the constructor of my HttpInterceptors. Any service that I attempt to inject into the service is met with the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'authenticationService' of undefined`

This goes for even a dummy `foo` service with a single function `bar` and no additional dependency injected into it.

**THE CODE**

*interceptor.ts*

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication/authentication.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.url.includes(location.hostname) && this.authenticationService.getToken()) {
            console.log('Headers added to the HTTP Request');
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authenticationService.getToken()}`
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

*authentication.service.ts*

```
import { OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthServiceConfig, AuthService as SocialAuthService, FacebookLoginProvider, GoogleLoginProvider, SocialUser} from 'angularx-social-login';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest } from  '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@Injectable( { providedIn: "root" } )

export class AuthenticationService implements OnInit{

  jwtHelper: JwtHelperService = new JwtHelperService();
  socialLoginConfig: AuthServiceConfig;
  loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<Boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<Boolean>(false);
  loggedIn$: Observable<Boolean> = this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  user: BehaviorSubject<SocialUser> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  user$: Observable<SocialUser> = this.user.asObservable();

  cachedRequests: Array<HttpRequest<any>> = [];

  constructor(private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user.next(user);
      this.loggedIn.next((user != null));
    });
  }

  provideConfig() {
    return this.socialLoginConfig;
  }

  getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  refreshToken(): void {
    // Need to add a call to refresh the token (JWT) to the backend.
  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = this.getToken();
    return token != null && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }

  collectFailedRequest(request): void {
    this.cachedRequests.push(request);
  }

  retryFailedRequests(): void {
    // Once the token has been refreshed, we can send previous failed requests from the cahcedRequests array...
  }

  signInWithGoogle(cb): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(
      (userData) => { //on success
        console.log('google', userData);
        this.user.next(userData);
        this.sendToRestApiMethod(userData.idToken, 'google', cb);
      }
    ).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error logging into Google Services:', err);
    });
  }

  signInWithFB(cb): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(
      (userData) => { //on success
        console.log('facebook', userData);
        this.user.next(userData);
        this.sendToRestApiMethod(userData.authToken, 'facebook', cb);
      }
    ).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error logging into Facebook Services:', err);
    });
  }

  signOut(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signOut();
    this.user.next(null);
  }

  sendToRestApiMethod(token: string, provider: string, cb) : void {
    this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl +'oauth2/authorization/' + provider, { token: token } )
      .subscribe(jwt => {
       console.log('login was successful', jwt);
       localStorage.setItem('token', jwt['jwt']);
       cb();
     }, onFail => {
        console.log('login was unsuccessful', onFail);
        //show an error message
     }
   );
 }
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { LoginComponent } from './modules/public/pages/login/login.component';
import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig } from "angularx-social-login";
import { GoogleLoginProvider, FacebookLoginProvider } from "angularx-social-login";

import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/components/footer/footer.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './modules/public/pages/home/home.component';
import { UserComponent } from './modules/secure/pages/user/user.component';

import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Interceptor } from './core/interceptors/interceptor';
import { DashboardComponent } from './modules/secure/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const socialLoginConfig = new AuthServiceConfig([
  { id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID, 
    provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(environment.google.clientid) },
  { id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID, 
    provider: new FacebookLoginProvider(environment.facebook.appid) }
]);

export function provideConfig() {
  return socialLoginConfig;
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    UserComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocialLoginModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: AuthServiceConfig, useFactory: provideConfig },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useFactory: Interceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*For people questioning the Angular version...*

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.3
Node: 11.7.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.2
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.3
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.3
@angular/cli                      7.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.3
@schematics/angular               7.2.3
@schematics/update                0.12.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.28.4
```

**Research/Troubleshooting Performed:**

I found various SO posts and [other forum posts](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224) describing issues when injecting a service that contains a HttpClient reference will cause a cyclic dependency error leading to the undefined, and authenticationService DOES have a reference to HTTPClient. However, according to the posts, this was fixed in an Angular 5 patch. As you can see, I'm currently using Angular 7 for this project.

I have attempted to follow these instructions and instead of injecting the `authenticationService` into the constructor, injecting an Injector and then performing:

`this.authenticationService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);`

This lead to the error:

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'injector' of undefined`

I've also tried to change the app.module.ts provider for the HttpInterceptor to the following:

`{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useFactory: Interceptor, multi: true, deps: [AuthenticationService] }`

This resulted in, yet again, the same undefined error.

**Conclusion:**

Apologies for the novel, but I wanted to ensure everyone had all possible information to help solve this issue that's caused me 3 days worth of headaches. Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Any chance that the services you're using in `Interceptor` themselves require the `HttpClient`? And shouldn't that be `useClass: Interceptor`?

Comment: `useClass: Interceptor`, and remove `{ providedIn: "root" }` on both

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh my god, how did I not see that...you're right, it should be useClass, not useFactory...doing that (also removed the providedIn: "root"- thanks William) fixed the problems...Thank you so much. If you'd like to pop in a quick answer, I'd love to mark it as correct so no one else ever has to deal with the stupid mistake I just did.

Comment: Sorry confused `AuthServiceConfig` with `AuthenticationService ` just remove `{ providedIn: "root" }` from `Interceptor`

Comment: @WilliamLohan Yup, I did that as well, but simply changing to useClass instead of useFactory fixed my problem.

Comment: Right it will work but you are providing `Interceptor` as its self in root and as a `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` which now that I think about it isn't bad just un-needed unless you need to inject `Interceptor` somewhere else (also if that were the case you may have to use `useExisting` to keep it a singleton)

Comment: @WilliamLohan Good call, definitely don't want a prototype implementation for an interceptor :)

Comment: @AaronUllal What do you mean? The providedIn root simply means that you don't need to import it into your app modules dependencies and makes it available globally. Not sure what your question is in regards to.

Comment: @RyanC never mind I had forgotten the @Injectable() decorator...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem of yours and I solved by switching from `useFactory` to `useClass` in the declaration of the module:

This was a working Angular 7.1 code

```js
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useFactory(router: Router, authenticationStorageService: AuthenticationStorageService) {
        // a lot of stuff here

        return new AuthInterceptor(router, authenticationStorageService);
    },
    multi: true,
    deps: [Router, AuthenticationStorageService]
},
```

which is broken in Angular 8. Throwing away the factory solves the issue:

```js
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true,
    deps: [Router, AuthenticationStorageService]
},
```

I had to shift the factory logic in the constructor of the class though. The factory approach was more flexible as you could change the returned instance from time to time, but probably an overkill in the standard case.

Comment: `useClass` did not work for me on Angular 15, but `useFactory` did! Thank you!