# How to properly call service methods from interceptor in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to build an error interceptor in my angular app. I imported the auth service into it through the constructor. But I am getting an error when I call a method from it that it does not exist. This is the interceptor.

```
 import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import {
    HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
    ){

    }
     intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }

    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if(error.status === 401){
            this.authService.logout();            
        }
        return throwError(error);
    }
}
```

And this is my auth-service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    url = 'http://localhost:3000/users/login'
    isLoggedIn = false;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    redirectUrl: string;

    login(credentials): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(this.url, credentials).pipe(catchError(err => {
            return throwError(err);
        }));
    }


    logout(): void {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }


    getAuthToken(): string{
        return localStorage.getItem('token');
    }
}
```

After I try to run it, I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'logout' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use arrow function notation to denote the class using `this` keyword in callbacks. Try the following

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    catchError((error) => this.handleError(error))    // <-- use arrow function here
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I thought it wasn't necessary since I was calling handle error without parentheses

Comment: It isn't required if you aren't trying to access member variables/properties using the `this` keyword in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

there is an answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60140852/9983888) but it was difficult to find.

When providing dependencies to inject into your Interceptors, you need to declare them under the `deps` key in the same object that defined your Interceptor in your Module. The following is an example:

```
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
    deps: [AuthService]
},
```

Hope this helps